# Socket Programming PF Packet Socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, hex

I am writing a code to communicate via the `SOCK_RAW` sockets with a process on another computer.

I know the IP address of the other machine.

I am aware that filling up the `sockaddr_ll.sll_addr` values one byte at a time will solve the problem i.e something like

```
socket_address.sll_addr[0]  = 0x00;     
socket_address.sll_addr[1]  = 0x04;     
socket_address.sll_addr[2]  = 0x75;
socket_address.sll_addr[3]  = 0xC8;
socket_address.sll_addr[4]  = 0x28;
socket_address.sll_addr[5]  = 0xE5;
```

But I don't know how to do the same thing when I have character array of 6 bytes having the hexadecimal address of the other machine.

I am able to print the hex address in ':' format using

```
printf("%.2x",*ptr++ & 0xff);
```

where `ptr` is an array to the character array.

But how to use these values to fill the `sll_addr` bytes?

Comment: I am confused, why can't you just do `socket_address.sll_addr[0] = ptr[0];` etc?

Comment: You are probably right. When posting my answer I somehow ignored the OP mentioning a ***6*** bytes character array, but silently assumed the source to be a string (which would be 17+1bytes). @Wutz

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `sscanf()` function to do this, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>

const char sMac[] = "01:02:03:04:05:ff";

int main()
{
  struct sockaddr_ll sa = {0};

  sscanf(sMac, "%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx",
    &sa.sll_addr[0],
    &sa.sll_addr[1],
    &sa.sll_addr[2],
    &sa.sll_addr[3],
    &sa.sll_addr[4],
    &sa.sll_addr[5]
  );

  return 0; 
}
```

The magic is the format string passed to `sscanf()`.

It tells the scanner where to find what in which range.

- `x` tells it to expect hexadecimal notation
- `hh` specifies 8bit values.